# Передача аргументов в функцию

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток, возможно будет глупенький вопрос, но охота сделать красиво, сильно не ругайте :)

Имеется, допустим, следующий код, в нем же и вопрос:

```
function OrderAjax(param) {
    this.emptyDetailPicture = param.emptyDetailPicture;
    this.jsData = param.jsData;
}

OrderAjax.prototype = {
    constructor: OrderAjax,

    renderBasket: function() {
        $.each(this.jsData['items'], function(index, item) {
            //Как вот сюда красиво достать значение this.emptyDetailPicture?
        });
    }
}
```

Заранее спасибо :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class OrderAjax {
  constructor({emptyDetailPicture, jsData}){
    this.emptyDetailPicture = emptyDetailPicture;
    this.jsData = jsData;
  }

  renderBasket(){
    $.each(this.jsData['items'], (index, item) => {
      console.log(this.emptyDetailPicture);
      // все дело в стрелочной функции которая сохраняет контекст объявления

        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

es5

```
OrderAjax.prototype = {
    renderBasket: function() {
     $.each(this.jsData['items'], this._ProcessData.bind(this));
    },
    _ProcessData: function(index, item){
        console.log(this.emptyDetailPicture);
    }
}
```